# Dictionary List <string, int> check if contains, sum values and put a textbox the string genarated

Tags: c#

Well, i have a dictionary . And i need to check if have the value inside in the directionary. If the itens exists, i need to return a sum of then. If not, just show a mesage or a Exception to inform this.

```
    Dictionary<string, int> ListaSubstituicao = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    ListaSubstituicao.Add("A", 1);
    ListaSubstituicao.Add("B", 5);
    ListaSubstituicao.Add("C", 10);
    ListaSubstituicao.Add("D", 50);
    ListaSubstituicao.Add("E", 100);
    ListaSubstituicao.Add("F", 500);
    ListaSubstituicao.Add("G", 1000);

   try
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> valorchave in ListaSubstituicao)
        {
            textoconverter = textoconverter.Replace(valorchave.Key.ToString(), valorchave.Value.ToString());
            txtconversaocaracteres.Text = textoconverter;

            //definindo a mensagem que irá aprecer no lblmsg ao converter com sucesso
            lblmsg.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            lblmsg.Text = "Success";

        }
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("text message", "title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        //definindo a mensagem que irá aparecer no lblmsg ao chamar a Exceção
        lblmsg.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
        lblmsg.Text = "Houston we have a problem!";
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your code does not appear to reflect your question at all. There is nothing to sum, the dictionary value is a single item. And if you loop over your dictionary then every key will exist.

Comment: textoconverter = textoconverter.Replace(valorchave.Key.ToString(), valorchave.Value.ToString()); -- This part does nothing if i am not wrong. 
Textoconverter is a string  variable I suppose and it was not set with any value in your code.
The Replace function cannot replace something, that is not there

Comment: How a i can to do this at all?! I need to validate three things: If you input A,B,C,D,E,F,G only he will sum the int values. Ex.: GGA = 2001. And you type anyone different of then a messagebox appears saying: "doesn't exists in dictionary" and if the value contains the A,B,C,D,E,F,G put only the sum on a text box.

Comment: @EymardSilva your comment makes sense, you might want to add that to the question. The code doesn't look anything like an attempt to do that. It sounds like you need to split the user input on each character, for each character look up the dictionary value and add it to an accumulating variable. Give that a try and come back if you have specific issues.

Comment: @Crowcoder i'll try. Thx for the advice with "split the user input on each character" this is helpfully.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
// use a variable to hold the sum
int sum = 0;

// iterate all characters in the string
foreach(var ch in textoconverter.ToArray())
    // lookup in dictionary
    if(ListaSubstituicao.TryGet(ch.ToString(), out var value))
        // add to the sum, when it was found.
        sum += value;

MessageBox.Show($"Sum of found characters is {sum}");
```

The TryGet returns a boolean to check if the value was found in the dictionary. If yes, then the `out var value` contains that value. Throwing any exception is not usefull here, because it's not exceptional.

If you want stop checking, because an invalid character is present. you could do something like:

```
// use a variable to hold the sum
int sum = 0;
// a boolean to hold the result of checking the characters
bool isValid = true;

// iterate all characters in the string
foreach(var ch in textoconverter.ToArray())
    // lookup in dictionary
    if(ListaSubstituicao.TryGet(ch.ToString(), out var value))
        // add the value to sum
        sum += value;
    else
    {
        // the character wasn't found, so the input was invalid
        isValid = false;
        // we need to stop processing
        break;
    }

// if isValid is true, only valid characters were found.
if(isValid)
     MessageBox.Show($"Sum of found characters is {sum}");
else
     MessageBox.Show($"Houston we have a problem!");
```

Don't forget that this is case sensitive. If you want it to be case insensitive, use the `textoconverter.ToUpper().ToArray()` instead.

Comment: you really help me. Thx for the advice with the unecessary use of the Exception! :)